# Multiple alignments and breaks

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I am trying to break one vector to two lines in combination with an align environment. Assume the following reproducible example

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 Two vectors of the form 
\begin{align*}
&1. \ \beta= (4.5, 2.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.5 ,0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0,0, 4,0,1.5, 2.5, 0,0,0,0,4,5,4.5,0,0,0,0,0,4.5,3.5,0,0,0)^T \\
&2. \ \beta_j= [0.7;0.9], \quad  j=1,...,35. 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to break the first line after the second "2.5" value, that the last 17 numbers should display in a new row aligned under the first value "4.5" of the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I think this comes closest to what you are looking for. I've used `array` and `flalign`. Also to get the equal signs aligned, I've used `_{\phantom{v}}` on the first line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

Two vectors of the form 
\begin{flalign*}
\begin{array}{ll}
1. \ \beta_{\phantom{j}} = (&4.5, 2.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.5 ,0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0,0, 4,0,1.5, 2.5,  \\ 
                &0,0,0,0,4,5,4.5,0,0,0,0,0,4.5,3.5,0,0,0)^T \\
2. \ \beta_j = [&0.7;0.9], \quad  j=1,...,35. 
\end{array} &&   
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

**Original answer**

Here is a proposal using `alignat`, which allows you to have multiple alignment points.

As an aside, careful with your preamble. You had `a5paper` and `a4paper` options loaded. Also, note that `mathtools` already loads `amsmath`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 Two vectors of the form 
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&1. \ \beta= (&&4.5, 2.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.5 ,0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0,0, 4,0,1.5, 2.5,\\ 
&              &&0,0,0,0,4,5,4.5,0,0,0,0,0,4.5,3.5,0,0,0)^T \\
&2. \ \beta_j= [&&0.7;0.9], \quad  j=1,...,35. 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

If you want the equation flush left, then you could use `flalign` like so.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Two vectors of the form 
\begin{flalign*}
1. \ \beta = (&4.5, 2.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.5 ,0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0,0, 4,0,1.5, 2.5, & \\ 
               &0,0,0,0,4,5,4.5,0,0,0,0,0,4.5,3.5,0,0,0)^T &\\
2. \ \beta_j = [&0.7;0.9], \quad  j=1,...,35. &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great ! I cant vote up the answer, since I have under 15 reputations

Comment: I would suggest to even use a third alignment for the equation sign after beta, so that they are aligned

Comment: Is there a way to align the numbering, so that "1." and "2." are left aligned as in the flalign environment

Comment: I added an update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `align`, but `enumerate` in combination with `multlined`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm,top=30mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Two vectors of the form 
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\beta=\begin{multlined}[t]
             (4.5, 2.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.5 ,0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0,0, 4,0,1.5, 2.5,\\
              0,0,0,0,4,5,4.5,0,0,0,0,0,4.5,3.5,0,0,0)^T
      \end{multlined}$
\item $\beta_j= [0.7;0.9]$, $j=1,\dots,35$. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]